# Double while loop

Tags: linux, bash

i have a double while loop like this:

```
while read file; do
  while read directory; do
    aux=$(find $directory -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "$file" | wc -l)
    if test $aux -ge 1; then
      find $directory -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "$file"
      //
    fi
  done < dir_file.txt
done < files.txt
```

I'm trying to locate files in uniq directories.. i need an instrunction after `//` which would change the `$file` with the next one... I tried `continue` but it changes the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `continue 2`. The numeric parameter counts the number of loops outwards. `continue` without a parameter equals `continue 1`.

Comment: Would you kindly mark the question as answered, so that others can find the solution?